# Typescript - Create new type excluding props of "never" type

Tags: typescript

In Typescript v4.x, I am trying to create a new type from another type (class/interface) where all the props of `never` type are excluded and not in the new type.

For example, given an interface:

```
interface A { propNever: never; propAnother: string; }
```

I would like to generate a new derivative type with the `propNever` prop excluded:

```
type B = { propAnother: string; };
```

So far I've tried the below approach:

```
type OmitNeverProps<T> = Pick<T, ({[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends never ? never : P })[keyof T]>;
```

But no luck - my Typescript inspections indicate that propNever: never; is still in the `type B`.

Any ideas if there is a way at all to exclude `never`-type props?

Comment: Tried this in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAICC6De6AOcA9vgHIwBu8AXOhJfANwHH6YRFQAWN6AzlDiQA5swC+oKAE98GAPIBbMFHJU4ABVZ8APABUAfOgC86dWBQBrPQBp0AChwBtdekjoLMKUQTpdAXVpdZz90GAAPWAgAEz46Bjh0AH44tXRaFzEASkcPLx9-fVBJGQwAIWN0RWVVeE0SHUx9ZgB6ZvQACSI1EXQAYX4uIgB3Plo8QhJ2Th44WgEhCGF0CRBQKJgUABskOAwUIggBdAAjWlLGUGOAOgm2Dm4mS5vWGrgWtrrZOGl0AHJb16-dBRIgwWL3UJhMBHA7oaSyP5mSzaTC2ABEtymDzgaP0vyuoCAA), v 4.1. Seems to be working as-is.

Comment: Indeed it does - I was actually trying to exclude an interface `function prop` returning never, i.e. `propMethodReturningNever(): never`.

Any ideas how to exclude never-returning functions?

Comment: I updated my answer that will handle functions too.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the [`ReturnType<F>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) built in will help for that. Modify your filter to check `ReturnType<T[P]> extends never`.

Comment: Please consider editing the text of this question to accurately reflect the problem you're having, since the code in the question as stated does not constitute a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

TS 4.1.2

```
interface A { funcNever(): never; propNever: never; propAnother: string; }

type OmitNeverProps<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never | ((...arg:any) => never) ? never : K]: T[K] } 

type B = OmitNeverProps<A>;

//type B = {
//    propAnother: string;
//}
```

TS 4.0.5

```
type OmitNeverProps<T> = Pick<T, ({[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends never | ((...arg:any) => never) ? never : P })[keyof T]>;
```

Comment: I get syntax errors as soon I post the above `type OmitNeverProps` line into my IDE (Typescript 4.0.5) - but works fine in Typescript 4.1.3. Thanks!

Comment: Marked your answer as the solution, though would be useful to find a way to run on TS 4.0.5 too, which probably does not support the newer syntax of the above answer.

Comment: I'll take a peek and see if I can make it work with 4.0.5

Comment: A small change to your original answer (including never functions) makes it work in 4.0.5. Updated answer.

Comment: Actually, when I use TS 4.0.5 variant, I get a lot of `TS2577: Return type annotation circularly references itself.` errors, i.e: `OmitNeverPropsTS405<Omit<BASE, keyof EXT> & EXT>`.

TS 4.1.2 variant works nicely without errors.

Comment: I was using TypeScript playground to check 4.0.5, not sure why IDE is different.